# A question about Weyl group action in the book of Bourbaki.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $(W,S)$ be a Coxeter group. Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with a basis $e_s$, $s \in S$.

In the book [Lie groups and Lie algebras, Chapters 4--6](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540691716), page 94, it is said that the Weyl group acts $V$ by 
\begin{align}
\sigma_s(e_{s'}) = e_{s'} + 2 \cos \frac{\pi}{m(s,s')} e_s, \quad (1)
\end{align}
where $s, s' \in S$, $m(s,s')$ is the order of $ss'$.

The root system is $\{w(e_s) \mid s \in S, w \in W\}$.

I am trying to verify that this coincides with the usual formua: 
\begin{align}
s_i(\alpha_j) = \alpha_j - c_{ji} \alpha_i,  \quad (2)
\end{align}
where $(c_{ij})$ is the Cartan matrix.

In type $B_2$, $S = \{s_1, s_2\}$, $m_{s_1, s_2}=4$. Therefore (1) is
\begin{align}
\sigma_{s_1}(e_{s_2}) = e_{s_2} + \sqrt{2} e_{s_1}, \\
\sigma_{s_2}(e_{s_1}) = e_{s_1} + \sqrt{2} e_{s_2}.  \quad (3)
\end{align}
Denote by $e_i = e_{s_i}$, $i=1,2$. The root system is $\pm \{e_1, e_2, e_1 + \sqrt{2} e_2, e_2 + \sqrt{2} e_1\}$. But the root system of type $B_2$ should be of the form $\pm \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_1+\alpha_2, \alpha_1+2\alpha_2\}$.

The formulas of (2) and (3) are also different. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does it say that the "root system is $\{w(e_s) \mid s \in S, w \in W\}$" in the source? I don't think that's the case. But up to scaling it might be: If you set $\alpha_1 := \sqrt{2}e_1$, $\alpha_2 := e_2$, you get the right formulae $\sigma_1(\alpha_2) = \alpha_2+\alpha_1$, $\sigma_2(\alpha_1) = \alpha_1 +2\alpha_2$.